# How to auto implement/generate methods in kotlin like in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

So I'm fairly new to kotlin. How do you go about doing the following in Kotlin (In the subscribe part)?

```
animalObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

In java all i have to do is type "new Ob" and press enter. It then auto generates the methods that need to be implemented. (the above)

This is the only way i have figured it out in Kotlin. I have to type in the following: "subscribe(object: Observer{})

```
animalsObserve
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(object : Observer<String> {

        })
```

Then can i generate the methods by doing command N (on a mac)

[image]

I'm sure there has to be a different way to do this?

Comment: You should typically use a DisposableObserver instead

Answer (score 0):

You are right: to construct an anonymous class you should use an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions). So in your example you'd do exactly as you state above, namely:

```
...
.subscribe(object : Observer<String>() {
    // Implementation of interface goes here
})
```

IntelliJ will highlight the `object` keyword with a red squiggle telling you that it's not implementing the interface, so you can then click on it and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (on Linux) which will give you the option to implement the members of `Observer`.

Alternatively you can click inside the block and use your normal shortcut (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on Linux) to bring up the "Override Members" dialog you've shown above.